# An issue with displaying the contents responsively from the hamburger menu when in mobile width

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, responsive

I'm new to the web development scene and I decided that I would make an E-Commerce website to strengthen my skills. In order to make the site more responsive on mobile devices, I decided to go with a hamburger menu to hide the contents of the navbar. The issue is, that the hiding of the content works absolutely fine when the width is resized, however, nothing drops down even with the display-block property in place upon clicking the menu icon. Could someone please take a look at this code and let me know where exactly I might be going wrong?

CSS/HTML:

```css
* {
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.logobar {
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}

.logobar:hover {
    background-color: royalblue;
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    box-shadow : 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.logo {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9px;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    display : flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

nav {
    flex : 1;
    text-align: left;
}

nav ul {
    display :inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    
}

.container {
 
    margin: auto;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.col-2{
    flex-basis: 45%;
    min-width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
 
}
.col-2 img{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.col-2 h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 25px 0;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(95, 110, 245);
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: background 0.3s
    
}

.btn:hover{
    background-color: #2f3369;
}
.header{
    background: radial-gradient(#ffffff, #a8eafa);
}

.categories {
    margin: 65px 0;
}

.col-3{
    flex-basis: 30%;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.col-3 img{
    width: 100%;


}

.small-container {
    max-width:1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.col-4{
    flex-basis: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.col-4 img{
    width: 100%;

}

.title {
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto 80px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: rgb(98, 97, 97);
}

.title::after{
    content: '';
    background: #3b76ff;
    width: 80px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

}

h4{
    color:rgb(98, 97, 97);
    font-weight: normal;
}

.col-4 p{
    font-size: 14px;

}

.rating .fas{
    color:#f18e0d;
}

.col-4:hover{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.col-3:hover{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.offer{
    background: radial-gradient(#ffffff, #a8eafa);
    margin-top: 80px;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.col-2 .offer-img{
    padding: 50px;
}

small{
    color:rgb(98, 97, 97);
}

.testimonial{
    padding-top: 100px;

}

.testimonial .col-3{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    box-shadow : 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.testimonial .col-3 img{
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.testimonial .col-3:hover{
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.fas.fa-quote-left{
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #db2f7f;
}

.col-3 p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 12px 0;
    color: rgb(138, 133, 133);
}

.testimonial .col-3 h3{
    font-weight: 600;
    color:rgb(98, 97, 97);
    font-size: 16px;
}

.brands{
    margin: 100px auto;

}

.col-5{
    width: 160px;

}

.col-5 img{
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.col-5 img:hover{
    filter: grayscale(0);
}

.footer{
    background: #000;
    color: #8a8a8a;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 60px 0 20px;
}

.footer p {
    color: #8a8a8a;

}

.footer h3{
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.footer-col-1, .footer-col-2, .footer-col-3, .footer-col-4 {
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

} 

.footer-col-1{
    flex-basis: 15%;
}
.footer-col-2{
    flex-basis: 15%;
    text-align: center;

}

.footer-col-2 img{
    width: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 7px;

}

.footer-col-3, .footer-col-4 {
    flex-basis: 12%;
    text-align:center;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.app-logo{
    margin-top: 20px;

}

.app-logo img{
    width: 140px;
}

.footer hr{
    border: none;
    background: #b5b5b5;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 20px 0;

}
.copyright{
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-icon{
    width: 28px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: nome;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left:0;
        background: #000;
        width:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.5s;
    }

    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        margin-right: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    nav ul li a{
        color: #fff;

    }
    .menu-icon {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .row{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .col-2, .col-3, .col-3{
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ShopEazy | Fast E-Commerce</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@100;200;300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 
       
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logobar">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src = "./assets/000749-online-store-logos-design-free-online-E-commerce-cart-logo-maker-04.png" width = "200px" style = "border-radius: 7.25%; box-shadow : 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
                </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="navbar" style = "background-color: black; position: relative;">
            <nav>
                <img src = "assets/menu.png" class = "menu-icon" onclick="menutoggle()" >
                <ul id = "menuitems">
                    <li><a href = "#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">ALL PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">CONTACT US</a></li>
    
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <span style = "text-align: right; padding: 8px;"><a href = "#" style="text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; color: aliceblue;"><i class="fas fa-user fa-lg"></i> ACCOUNT</a></span>
            <span style = "text-align: right; margin-right: 15px; padding: 2px;"><a href = "#" style="text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; color: aliceblue;"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i> CART</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <h1>
                    A new sale <br>for a new you!
                </h1>
                <p>Check out our new drip for up to 50%* off!</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn" style = "text-decoration: none;">
                    See More &#8594;
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <img src="./assets/NicePng_cr7-logo-png_3655520.png" height = "750px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="categories">
        <div class="small-container">
            <h2 class = "title">Featured Product Categories</h2><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="assets/pexels-athena-2081199.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="assets/pexels-melvin-buezo-2529157.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="assets/pexels-marius-mann-1697218.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-container">
        <h2 class = "title">
            Featured Items
        </h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/81Js5VhBhrL._UL1500.jpg">
                <h4>Blue Polo T-Shirt</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$30.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/61u7Yndrb4L._UL1200_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Running Shoe</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$30.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/71brLbCniXL._UL1500_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Black Dial Watch</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$70.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/91gxJ+bZdML._UL1500_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Casual Bagpack</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$40.00</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="title">Newest Launches</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/810yMve0VFL._UL1500_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Chinos</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    
                </div>
                <p>$25.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/71t9rfIGkYL._SL1200_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Triple Fold Wallet</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$25.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/61aJu9X3UkL._UL1400_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Premium Leather Belt</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                    
                </div>
                <p>$45.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/71ugBrc3mZL._UL1500_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Tracksuit</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$35.00</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="assets/61YFsC9LEKL._UL1500_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Formal Suit</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    
                </div>
                <p>$120.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/714xGAeUOgL._UL1500_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Metal Cufflinks</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$10.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/51Z5PJWp-cL._UL1100_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Stainless Steel Bracelet</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                    
                </div>
                <p>$20.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="assets/61nfXzkKAUL._UL1440_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Casual Tie</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$50.00</p>
            </div>
            </div>

    </div>

    <div class="offer">
        <div class="small-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <img src ="assets/K2-all-kv组合2-1024x1024.png" class="offer-img">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <p>Exclusive offer : <strong>Xiaomi Mi 11</strong> Now only on <strong>S</strong>hop<em style="color: green;">Eazy</em></p>
                    <h1>Xiaomi Mi 11</h1>
                    <small>Powered by the Snapdragon 888 5G processor high 4600mah battery capacity
                        and a high quality 1440p AMOLED fluid 120Hz display. 4K recording upto 120x Zoom with 108MP on camera.
                    </small><br>
                    <a href="#" class="btn" style="text-decoration: none;">Check out now! &#8594;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="small-container">
            <h2 class = "title">
                User Testimonials
            </h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-lg"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam voluptatem dignissimos nesciunt consectetur omnis culpa voluptas officia iusto minima ipsam architecto, quod eveniet a beatae facere! Praesentium possimus ad aliquid?</p>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <img src="assets/607c1978da4a4db6ab91977802ee4aba.jpg">
                    <h3>Michael Scott</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-lg"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam voluptatem dignissimos nesciunt consectetur omnis culpa voluptas officia iusto minima ipsam architecto, quod eveniet a beatae facere! Praesentium possimus ad aliquid?</p>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    </div>
                    <img src="assets/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80.jpg">
                    <h3>Sarah Miller</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-lg"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam voluptatem dignissimos nesciunt consectetur omnis culpa voluptas officia iusto minima ipsam architecto, quod eveniet a beatae facere! Praesentium possimus ad aliquid?</p>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <img src="assets/images.jpg">
                    <h3>Keith Parker</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brands">
        <div class="small-container">
            <h2 class = "title">
                Partner Brands
            </h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="assets/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c4f8.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="assets/5847eab1cef1014c0b5e4840.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="assets/60410c7b26ef2b00045692f8.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="assets/vh_blog_logo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="assets/d81630aab7cd4f000cc5d18f179bc50a.w800.h800.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="footer-col-1">
                    <h3>Get the app!</h3>
                    <p>Download for Android or iOS</p>
                    <div class="app-logo">
                        <img src ="assets/play-store.png">
                        <img src ="assets/app-store.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-col-2">
                    <img src="assets/000749-online-store-logos-design-free-online-E-commerce-cart-logo-maker-04.png">
                    <p>Cool gear for men at cheap prices. Always.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-col-3">
                    <h3>Useful stuff</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Freebies</li>
                        <li>Shopping Blog</li>
                        <li>Affiliate</li>
                        <li>Privacy Policy</li>
                    </ul>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="footer-col-4">
                    <h3>Socials</h3>
                    <ul style="display: inline-block;">
                        <li style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-3x"></i></li>
                        <li style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x"></i></li>
                        <li style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-3x"></i></li>
                        <li style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <p class = "copyright">Copyright 2021 - Aritra Chatterjee</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var menuitem = document.getElementById("menuitems");
        menuitem.style.maxHeight = "0px";
        function menutoggle() {
            if(menuitem.style.maxHeight == "0px")
                {
                    menuitem.style.maxHeight = "200px";
                }
            else{
                menuitem.style.maxHeight = "0px";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is working But your menu is coming underneath your webpage so use `z-index`

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav ul {
        z-index:100;
    }
}
```

DEMO:

```css
* {
    margin : 0;
    padding : 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: relative;
}

.logobar {
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
}

.logobar:hover {
    background-color: royalblue;
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    box-shadow : 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}

.logo {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 9px;
}

html, body {
    height:100%;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

.navbar {
    display : flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
}

nav {
    flex : 1;
    text-align: left;
}

nav ul {
    display :inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 5px;
}

nav ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: aliceblue;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    
}

nav ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    background-color: aliceblue;
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    
}

.container {
 
    margin: auto;
}

.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.col-2{
    flex-basis: 45%;
    min-width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
 
}
.col-2 img{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.col-2 h1{
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 60px;
    margin: 25px 0;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: rgb(95, 110, 245);
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    border-radius: 25px;
    transition: background 0.3s
    
}

.btn:hover{
    background-color: #2f3369;
}
.header{
    background: radial-gradient(#ffffff, #a8eafa);
}

.categories {
    margin: 65px 0;
}

.col-3{
    flex-basis: 30%;
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.col-3 img{
    width: 100%;


}

.small-container {
    max-width:1080px;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.col-4{
    flex-basis: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    min-width: 200px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.col-4 img{
    width: 100%;

}

.title {
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto 80px;
    position: relative;
    line-height: 60px;
    color: rgb(98, 97, 97);
}

.title::after{
    content: '';
    background: #3b76ff;
    width: 80px;
    height: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);

}

h4{
    color:rgb(98, 97, 97);
    font-weight: normal;
}

.col-4 p{
    font-size: 14px;

}

.rating .fas{
    color:#f18e0d;
}

.col-4:hover{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.col-3:hover{
    transform: translateY(-5px);
}

.offer{
    background: radial-gradient(#ffffff, #a8eafa);
    margin-top: 80px;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.col-2 .offer-img{
    padding: 50px;
}

small{
    color:rgb(98, 97, 97);
}

.testimonial{
    padding-top: 100px;

}

.testimonial .col-3{
    text-align: center;
    padding: 40px 20px;
    box-shadow : 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
}

.testimonial .col-3 img{
    width: 50px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 50%;

}

.testimonial .col-3:hover{
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}

.fas.fa-quote-left{
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #db2f7f;
}

.col-3 p {
    font-size: 12px;
    margin: 12px 0;
    color: rgb(138, 133, 133);
}

.testimonial .col-3 h3{
    font-weight: 600;
    color:rgb(98, 97, 97);
    font-size: 16px;
}

.brands{
    margin: 100px auto;

}

.col-5{
    width: 160px;

}

.col-5 img{
    width: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.col-5 img:hover{
    filter: grayscale(0);
}

.footer{
    background: #000;
    color: #8a8a8a;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 60px 0 20px;
}

.footer p {
    color: #8a8a8a;

}

.footer h3{
    color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

}

.footer-col-1, .footer-col-2, .footer-col-3, .footer-col-4 {
    min-width: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;

} 

.footer-col-1{
    flex-basis: 15%;
}
.footer-col-2{
    flex-basis: 15%;
    text-align: center;

}

.footer-col-2 img{
    width: 180px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 7px;

}

.footer-col-3, .footer-col-4 {
    flex-basis: 12%;
    text-align:center;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.app-logo{
    margin-top: 20px;

}

.app-logo img{
    width: 140px;
}

.footer hr{
    border: none;
    background: #b5b5b5;
    height: 1px;
    margin: 20px 0;

}
.copyright{
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-icon{
    width: 28px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display: nome;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    nav ul {
        position: absolute;
        top: 70px;
        left:0;
        background: #000;
        width:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        transition: max-height 0.5s;
        z-index:100;
    }

    nav ul li{
        display: block;
        margin-right: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    nav ul li a{
        color: #fff;

    }
    .menu-icon {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .row{
        text-align: center;
    }
    .col-2, .col-3, .col-3{
        flex-basis: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ShopEazy | Fast E-Commerce</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./css/style.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@100;200;300;400;500;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 
       
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logobar">
            <div class="logo">
                <img src = "./assets/000749-online-store-logos-design-free-online-E-commerce-cart-logo-maker-04.png" width = "200px" style = "border-radius: 7.25%; box-shadow : 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);">
                </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="navbar" style = "background-color: black; position: relative;">
            <nav>
                <img src = "assets/menu.png" class = "menu-icon" onclick="menutoggle()" >
                <ul id = "menuitems">
                    <li><a href = "#">HOME</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">ALL PRODUCTS</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">CONTACT US</a></li>
    
                </ul>
            </nav>
            <span style = "text-align: right; padding: 8px;"><a href = "#" style="text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; color: aliceblue;"><i class="fas fa-user fa-lg"></i> ACCOUNT</a></span>
            <span style = "text-align: right; margin-right: 15px; padding: 2px;"><a href = "#" style="text-decoration: none; font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif; color: aliceblue;"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg"></i> CART</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="header">
    <div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-2">
                <h1>
                    A new sale <br>for a new you!
                </h1>
                <p>Check out our new drip for up to 50%* off!</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn" style = "text-decoration: none;">
                    See More &#8594;
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <img src="./assets/NicePng_cr7-logo-png_3655520.png" height = "750px">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="categories">
        <div class="small-container">
            <h2 class = "title">Featured Product Categories</h2><br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="assets/pexels-athena-2081199.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="assets/pexels-melvin-buezo-2529157.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">
                <img src="assets/pexels-marius-mann-1697218.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="small-container">
        <h2 class = "title">
            Featured Items
        </h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/81Js5VhBhrL._UL1500.jpg">
                <h4>Blue Polo T-Shirt</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$30.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/61u7Yndrb4L._UL1200_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Running Shoe</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$30.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/71brLbCniXL._UL1500_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Black Dial Watch</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$70.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/91gxJ+bZdML._UL1500_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Casual Bagpack</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$40.00</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <h2 class="title">Newest Launches</h2>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/810yMve0VFL._UL1500_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Chinos</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    
                </div>
                <p>$25.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/71t9rfIGkYL._SL1200_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Triple Fold Wallet</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$25.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/61aJu9X3UkL._UL1400_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Premium Leather Belt</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                    
                </div>
                <p>$45.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/71ugBrc3mZL._UL1500_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Tracksuit</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$35.00</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="assets/61YFsC9LEKL._UL1500_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Formal Suit</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    
                </div>
                <p>$120.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/714xGAeUOgL._UL1500_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Metal Cufflinks</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$10.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src ="./assets/51Z5PJWp-cL._UL1100_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Stainless Steel Bracelet</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                    
                </div>
                <p>$20.00</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-4">
                <img src="assets/61nfXzkKAUL._UL1440_.jpg">
                <h4>Men's Casual Tie</h4>
                <div class="rating">
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                    <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                </div>
                <p>$50.00</p>
            </div>
            </div>

    </div>

    <div class="offer">
        <div class="small-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-2">
                    <img src ="assets/K2-all-kv组合2-1024x1024.png" class="offer-img">
                </div>
                <div class="col-2">
                    <p>Exclusive offer : <strong>Xiaomi Mi 11</strong> Now only on <strong>S</strong>hop<em style="color: green;">Eazy</em></p>
                    <h1>Xiaomi Mi 11</h1>
                    <small>Powered by the Snapdragon 888 5G processor high 4600mah battery capacity
                        and a high quality 1440p AMOLED fluid 120Hz display. 4K recording upto 120x Zoom with 108MP on camera.
                    </small><br>
                    <a href="#" class="btn" style="text-decoration: none;">Check out now! &#8594;</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="testimonial">
        <div class="small-container">
            <h2 class = "title">
                User Testimonials
            </h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-3">
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-lg"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam voluptatem dignissimos nesciunt consectetur omnis culpa voluptas officia iusto minima ipsam architecto, quod eveniet a beatae facere! Praesentium possimus ad aliquid?</p>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <img src="assets/607c1978da4a4db6ab91977802ee4aba.jpg">
                    <h3>Michael Scott</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-lg"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam voluptatem dignissimos nesciunt consectetur omnis culpa voluptas officia iusto minima ipsam architecto, quod eveniet a beatae facere! Praesentium possimus ad aliquid?</p>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star-half"></i>
                    </div>
                    <img src="assets/photo-1438761681033-6461ffad8d80.jpg">
                    <h3>Sarah Miller</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="col-3">
                    <i class="fas fa-quote-left fa-lg"></i>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aliquam voluptatem dignissimos nesciunt consectetur omnis culpa voluptas officia iusto minima ipsam architecto, quod eveniet a beatae facere! Praesentium possimus ad aliquid?</p>
                    <div class="rating">
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                        <i class="far fa-star"></i>
                    </div>
                    <img src="assets/images.jpg">
                    <h3>Keith Parker</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="brands">
        <div class="small-container">
            <h2 class = "title">
                Partner Brands
            </h2>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="assets/580b57fcd9996e24bc43c4f8.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="assets/5847eab1cef1014c0b5e4840.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="assets/60410c7b26ef2b00045692f8.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="assets/vh_blog_logo.png">
                </div>
                <div class="col-5">
                    <img src="assets/d81630aab7cd4f000cc5d18f179bc50a.w800.h800.png">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="footer-col-1">
                    <h3>Get the app!</h3>
                    <p>Download for Android or iOS</p>
                    <div class="app-logo">
                        <img src ="assets/play-store.png">
                        <img src ="assets/app-store.png">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-col-2">
                    <img src="assets/000749-online-store-logos-design-free-online-E-commerce-cart-logo-maker-04.png">
                    <p>Cool gear for men at cheap prices. Always.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-col-3">
                    <h3>Useful stuff</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>Freebies</li>
                        <li>Shopping Blog</li>
                        <li>Affiliate</li>
                        <li>Privacy Policy</li>
                    </ul>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="footer-col-4">
                    <h3>Socials</h3>
                    <ul style="display: inline-block;">
                        <li style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fab fa-facebook fa-3x"></i></li>
                        <li style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fab fa-youtube fa-3x"></i></li>
                        <li style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fab fa-twitter fa-3x"></i></li>
                        <li style="display: inline-block;"><i class="fab fa-instagram fa-3x"></i></li>
                    </ul>
                    
                </div>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <p class = "copyright">Copyright 2021 - Aritra Chatterjee</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var menuitem = document.getElementById("menuitems");
        menuitem.style.maxHeight = "0px";
        function menutoggle() {
            if(menuitem.style.maxHeight == "0px")
                {
                    menuitem.style.maxHeight = "200px";
                }
            else{
                menuitem.style.maxHeight = "0px";
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```